# Which method is called just before the session gets invalidated in spring-mvc life cycle?

Tags: spring-mvc, session-timeout

I'm trying to timeout an HttpSession in Spring-mvc.
When the session gets timed out I have to release the resources that were used.
For that I need to call some other methods in the application.

```
myService.releaseResources(id,name);
```

myService is an autowired object for the service class.

When the session gets timed out the sessionDestroyed method is called.
But in this method myService method value is null.
I want to know where should I call the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

   @Override
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
   }
}
```

Add its entry to web.xml

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>
       yourpacakage.SessionListener
      </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then call your desired code inside `sessionDestroyed` method.And as far as service is concerned you can get the service object by accessing current applicationContext.

```
ServletContext ctx = event.getSession().getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext springContext=WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ctx);
 springContext.getBean("yourService");
```

Comment: Hi Piyush,Thanks for your reply. But I have already implemented the HttpSessionListener.And have used autowired bean instance.So I have not used the springContext.getBean("yourService");  But in the sessionDestroyed method the bean instance value is null. Can you please tell me why is that happening and what should be done.

Comment: See autowire only works for spring managed beans....except those bean if you want an instance of spring-managed beans you need to explicitly get it from application context. –

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle things local to a particular session bean, you can use `@Predestroy` to annotate your releaseResources method.  That will inform Spring that you want that method to be invoked when the session ends.

Note that your MyService bean will have to be annotated to be session scoped.